# Why does my 'Calculator' object not have the 'current' attribute?

Tags: python

I've been trying to learn Python and wanted to practice by creating a module that could do addition and subtraction that looks like this:

```
class Calculator(object):
    def _init_(self):
        self.current = 0
    def add(self, amount):
        self.current += amount
    def sub(self, amount):
        self.current -= amount
    def getCurrent(self):
        return self.current
```

I then imported this module into IDLE and tried to use my add function like so:

```
c = Calculator()
c.add(2)
```

However, I ended up receiving an attribute error in reference to this line:
`self.current += amount'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    c.add(2)
  File "/Applications/Python 3.12/Python Stuff/ClassOne.py", line 5, in add
    self.current += amount
AttributeError: 'Calculator' object has no attribute 'current'
```

I'm pretty sure it's not an indentation error.

Comment: `_init_` isn't the same as `__init__`

Comment: First function should be called `__init__` (with a double underscore)

Comment: To debug this kind of thing on your own you can add `print()` statements in your code to check what function is called. For example you can do `print("in init")` inside your init function and `print("in add")` in your add function. This will check if they are being called like you think they are. Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need two underscores around `init`. You have `_init_` (which is never called), but you need to have `__init__`. This is true for all overloadable operators in python (`__add__`, `__getitem__`, etc)

getter and setter methods are unnecessary in python, given what you have here I'm guessing you're coming from Java. You can just expose your attributes (instance variables). If you later need to hide a field and provide special get/set functionality, you do so with a [`@property`](https://realpython.com/python-property/#getting-started-with-pythons-property), so, get rid of `getCurrent`.

You don't need to subclass `object` explicitly in Python 3. `class Calculator(object):` is the same as `class Calculator:`

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = 0

    def add(self, amount):
        self.current += amount

    def sub(self, amount):
        self.current -= amount
```